# Can't access the class instance declared in the same class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a preference window and need to detect if it is open or not. If it is open, I then close it. It it is closed, I open it. I declared a class instance in the class so I can access it in a case with a if statement. When I tried to access to it, it seems I can't. I can't access _prefsForm in the case. This is MVVM.

Here is the code:

```
   Private Views.Dialogs.Preferences _prefsForm;
      ....

       case 4:               
               if (_prefsForm == null)
               {
                     _prefsForm = new Views.Dialogs.Preferences();
                     wih = new WindowInteropHelper(_prefsForm);
                     wih.Owner = hwnd;
                     _prefsForm.Show();
                     _editorState = EditorState.DISPLAYPREFS;

                }
                else
                {
                    _prefsForm.Hide();
                    _editorState = EditorState.VIEWDATA;
                    _prefsForm = null;

                }

              break;
            }
```

Comment: is it a typo in the question or have you got two variables: `prefsForm` and `_prefsForm` ?

Comment: Also please elaborate on what you mean by "can't access"

Comment: "This is MVVM."... I'm afraid not... On a serious note, may you please give us the exact exception you get and is the variable initialized?

Comment: This surely is a duplicate, no (i.e. "object reference not set to an instance of an object", etc.")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to keep a reference to your open `Window` objects. You can access your open `Window` like this:

```
Views.Dialogs.Preferences preferencesWindow = null;
foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    if (window is Views.Dialogs.Preferences)
    {
        preferencesWindow = (Views.Dialogs.Preferences)window;
        break;
    }
}
if (preferencesWindow.Visiblity == Visibility.Visible) preferencesWindow.Hide();
else preferencesWindow.Show();
```

If you just have one of these `Window`s, it is even easier using `Linq`:

```
using System.Linq;
using Views.Dialogs;
...
Preferences preferencesWindow = 
    Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Preferences>().First();
```

Actually, using `Linq` makes it easier even if you have more than one of these `Window`s:

```
using System.Linq;
using Views.Dialogs;
...
Preferences preferencesWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Preferences>().
    Where(w => w.Name = NameOfYourWindow).First();
```